# Electric Baseboard Heater Thermostat Replacement

Tags: thermostat, heater

My house is mostly steam heat, but prior owners put on a small addition and also  turned an upstairs closet into a bathroom. These new rooms have electric baseboard heat.

Heaters work fine, but thermostats are crummy. Especially in the bathroom. It only functions as an on off switch at the moment so I want to replace that one.

I'm handy enough not to kill myself swapping it out, but not well enough informed to pick out a replacement.

The bathroom is heated by a single heater with a label indicating:

> 750W @208VAC
>
> 1000W @240VAC

The existing Thermostat has a label indicating:

> 125/250/277 VAC
>
> 22A Double pole

Attached are pictures of the the spec label on the heater (the bathroom only has one of the smaller baseboard units) and the existing thermostat.

I cant find these exact specs in a replacement thermostat. Specifically I'm finding sats rated for 240v, 3600W, and 15A So my question is: **Can I use any line volt stat rated for greater than or equal to 1000W and 240V** or are there other considerations? For a single 1000W heater, the existing 22A stat seems overkill, no?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any thermostat rated at or above the heater ratings should work fine. 3600W is a good number because that is 15A @ 240V, which is also a common breaker size. My guess is that the original installer used the same thermostats everywhere, costing a little more but minimizing the number of inventory items. 3600W/15A also allows you to upgrade a bit in the future without replacing the thermostat.

Comment: Keep in mind that heaters need a 125% derate, so a 15A breaker can only power 12A of heater.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, but didn't know for sure. But even at that, 1500W (the larger of the 2 existing heaters, 6A) is well within range, and a total could be up to 12A = 2,880 - much larger than the existing heaters. Plus we're only guessing that the existing wiring & breakers are 15A as a minimum. For all we know, the wiring & breaker might be rated for 20A.

Comment: it's tied to two 20A breakers - which i believe makes it a 240v supply that would still trip at 20A

Comment: So the 20a breakers would trip before the stat fries at 22a

Comment: Just as important is that the breakers would trip before the wires fry.

Comment: @Harper  , can you clarify the 125% derate for me?  As I noted above, my bathroom and living rooms EACH have their own 240v 20a breakers. For my living room (two of the smaller 1000W heaters and one larger 1500W)  I really want to get away from mechanical stats.  The "Mysa Smart Thermostat for Electric Baseboard Heaters" states it's good for 3800W & 16A...obviously this isn't a full on professional consult, but does that set up raise any red flags?

Comment: When sizing a breaker for a heater or any *continuous load*, take its amps and multiply by 125%. *You need that much breaker for it*.  For instance say you have a 12A heater and a 3A bathroom fan on a timer, which is not a continuous load.  You cannot put both on a 15A breaker.  You compute 125% of 12A which is 15A, add the 3A, total 18A - that fits with room to spare on a 20A breaker.

Comment: @Zipper1365 most people actually do it backwards because the math is easier: if you pretend all loads are continuous,  you work backwards and multiply the breaker by 80%, e.g. A 15A breaker can support 12A of continuous load or heater.  A 20A breaker would support 16A, which again would fit the 12A heater + 3A fan in the above example. (This ignores the fact that the fan is not a continous load, but that makes little difference, and it is simpler to think about.)

Comment: @Harper thanks for expanding on that. To be clear though, that applies to sizing the breaker ONLY and not the current rating on a thermostat, itself, right?  So my living room's 3500w baseboards at 240v suck about 14.6A and would fit the 16amp derate on my 20amp breaker.  And there is no need to derate the thermostat rating too which states its good to 16 amps. Correct? I assume this is precisely why the thermostat comes rated at 16A - a number which I had previously thought be be oddly arbitrary!

Comment: @Zipper1365 sounds right to me, since the thermostat is designed specifically for loads that are always rated as continuous loads.  Indeed, a magic number that is 80% of a common breaker rating is a good indication.

Answer (score 1):

### There‘s no such thing as a cheaper, smaller thermostat

Because of diminishing returns, there just isn't much manufacturing cost savings to be had on a 10A thermostat vs. a 20A or 30A thermostat.  As such, there's a minimum size they'll make.  Your needs will be below that minimum.

What's more, even 30A thermostats are *cheeeep.* When a big one costs $12, there's no point making a little one for $11.

Buy the thermostat you want and don't worry about it.

Comment: I wasn't too concerned about finding a cheaper one. I was more just asking to confirm that I need not match the existing 22 amp as it is overkill for my system as i have been having a damn hard time finding a programmable line volt stat in 22amp.  15amps are more plentiful.

Comment: Oh, well if you want to fantastically fatten your choices for thermostat, add a 24V transformer and 24V A/C contactor (which are rated for motor loads, resistor loads are much easier on the contacts) and that will let you use *any* common 24V thermostat like a Nest. We have Q&A that address that.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds a bit beyond my present skill/comfort level, but I'm going to look into that as an upgrade option later on. Thanks